# Distinguish Categorical Variables by Color using leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm making an interactive map of a population in the D.C. area using "leaflet" in R, and I want to use different colors to distinguish the 7 different communities. My variables are: address, community, gender, and name(for the pop-ups). I used some of the code from [TrendCt](http://trendct.org/2015/06/26/tutorial-how-to-put-dots-on-a-leaflet-map-with-r/) and [Ripples](https://aschinchon.wordpress.com/2015/09/08/a-simple-interactive-map-of-us-prisons-with-leaflet/).

How would I tweak my code to show the different colors for different communities, and maybe even how could I have change the shades to distinguish by gender in the communities?

Here is my code:

```
###########################################################################
#################### D.C. Community Map in R ##############################
###########################################################################

## Retrieve Data and Download Package
# Use import data set dropdown menu to import data correctly
# Community Map.csv 

# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)

# Define new data set
ysa <- Community.Map

## Generate dataset with coordinate variables 
## Averages 10 minutes to render on my i5 processor
ysa %>% 
  mutate(address=paste(gender, sep=", ", ward)) %>%
  select(address) %>% 
  lapply(function(x){geocode(x, output="latlon")})  %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  cbind(ysa) -> ysa1

ysa %>%  
  mutate(popup_info=paste(sep = "<br/>", paste0("<b>","<i>", ward,"<i>", "      
  </b>"), name)) %>% 
  mutate(lon=ifelse(is.na(longitude), address.lon, longitude),
         lat=ifelse(is.na(latitude),  address.lat, latitude)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(lon) & !grepl("CLOSED", ward)) -> ysa2

# Plot the map
leaflet(ysa2) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lng = ~longitude, 
                   lat = ~latitude, 
                   radius = 1.5, 
                   color = "red",
                   stroke=FALSE,
                   fillOpacity = 0.8,
                   popup = ~popup_info) %>%
addLegend("bottomright", colors= "red", labels="Community ", title="YSA     
Bounderies by Community")
```

I have been attempting to divide by colors using the following code:

```
# color <- colorFactor(c("blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "brown", "gold", "purple"),    
domain = c("Braddock", "Shenandoah", "Langley", "DC 2nd", "Colonial 1st", 
"Colonial 2nd", "Glenn Dale"))
```

Essentially, I want to assign a different color per community, like attempted in the above text, but I'm missing something. Please share if you have ideas.

Comment: Where does `Community.Map` come from? This isn't reproducible without it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you haven't connected the colour palette you created to the data and the legend. Try something along the lines of:

```
library(viridis) # My favorite palette for maps
wardpal <- colorFactor(viridis(7), ysa2$ward) # I'm assuming the variable ward contains the names of the communities.

leaflet(ysa2) %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
    addCircleMarkers(lng = ~longitude, 
                       lat = ~latitude, 
                       radius = 1.5, 
                       fillColor = ~wardpal(ward),
                       stroke=FALSE,
                       fillOpacity = 0.8,
                       popup = ~popup_info) %>%
    addLegend("bottomright", pal = wardpal, values = ~ward, labels = "Community ", title = "YSA Bounderies by Community")
```

You also want to encode gender in the colour shading. Have you tried mapping fillOpacity to a variable describing gender distribution (e.g., `fillOpacity = ~ percent_female`). Alternatively, you could add a separate layer for each community, setting the palette for each layer based on gender prevalence. You can tie all the layers together using the 'group' parameter within each addCirlayer call.

Comment: This was very helpful and did the trick! I appreciate it Peter K. I am testing out the layer suggestion now.